disabling resolv.conf for Samba installation
Hi I would like to configure an Ubuntu server 24.04 as an AD Domain Controller using Samba.
Reading the Samba Wiki, I find that one of the prerequisites is to disable the automatic update of /etc/resolv.conf.
I read a lot of forum entries, but I wasn't able to guess the best option to do. I understood that using netplan configuration should be the best option, but it's not clear how to do it.
Several attempts lead me to a corruption of the DNS service.
References:

Samba Wiki

